# Переменная в названии столбца в условии Select'a

Tags: mysql, select

Столбцы таблицы названы номерами. Переменной присваивается некое число. Затем значение переменной должно подставляться в запрос и распознаваться как название столбца в условии, по которому идет выборка.

Пробую так:

```
SELECT country FROM first_base WHERE `(@$q1)`="*";
```

Получаю ошибку: Unknown column '(@$q1)' in 'where clause'.

Если подставить, например, `14` в кавычках, то выборка делается. Если (@$q1) без кавычек - процесс идет, но совпадений нет - число из переменной не рассматривается в качестве имени столбца, как я понимаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно сделать запрос на выборку?

Comment: правильно понимаете, из переменной невозможно брать имена объектов. имя должно быть подставлено не в сама sql а в том языке из которого вы вызываете запрос. Хотя стоит задуматься о изменении структуры БД, что бы любые запрашиваемые переменными значения были в БД именно в виде значений а не в виде имен. например развернуть таблицу что бы на каждое значение была отдельная строка и требуемый номер лежал в поле

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Помогла первая часть вашего совета+корректировка названия столбцов таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Если не менять структуру, довольно, надо признать, странную, то надо либо делать хранимую процедуру с prepared statement внутри, либо писать бред вроде

```
where (@sql=1 and `1`='*')
   or (@sql=2 and `2`='*')
   or (@sql=3 and `3`='*')
-- ...
```